# Simplify $\sqrt[3]\frac{-81y^7 z^2}{3yz^5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

"Simplify the radical expression completely. Use absolute value symbols if and only if needed. Rationalize all denominators and eliminate the negative exponents."

$\sqrt[3]\frac{-81y^7 z^2}{3yz^5}$

Comment: Hey. If you want the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, you should type \frac{a}{b} encapsulated by dollar signs.

Comment: Do you want $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{-81y^7z^2}{3yz^5}}?$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{-81y^7z^2}{3yz^5}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{-27y^6}{z^3}}=-\frac{3y^2}{z}$$